# WSO2 APIM GW issue of traffic manager with JMS listner

Tags: wso2

In my setup WSO2, the Traffic manager is running into AWS infra and WSO2 GW is running on Azure.
but I am getting below error when trying to start my GW.

```
2020-10-09 06:42:11,354] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2020-10-09 06:42:11,355] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2020-10-09 06:42:11,358] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2020-10-09 06:42:11,359] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
```

I am using the following code into gw .toml and the traffic manager is running with an offset value as 3

```
    [apim.throttling]
    service_url = "https://tm.wso2.dev:9446/services/"
    username= "admin_tm"
    password= "admin_tm"
    enable_data_publishing = true
    enable_policy_deploy = false
    enable_blacklist_condition = true
    enable_decision_connection = true
    enable_advanced_throttling = true
    enable_unlimited_tier = true
    enable_header_based_throttling = false
    enable_jwt_claim_based_throttling = false
    enable_query_param_based_throttling = false
    throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://tm.wso2.dev:5675"]
    [[apim.throttling.url_group]]
    traffic_manager_urls=["tcp://tm.wso2.dev:9614"]
    traffic_manager_auth_urls=["ssl://tm.wso2.dev:9714"]
```

Comment: Seems like gateways are failing to connect the JMS server in traffic manager. can you make sure tcp://tm.wso2.dev:5675 endpoints are up using telnet or something?

Comment: Yes, able to telnet and traceroute both, any suggestion please!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with removing service url and see? Sample config here below,

```
[apim.throttling]
username= "admin_tm"
password= "admin_tm"
enable_unlimited_tier = true
enable_header_based_throttling = false
enable_jwt_claim_based_throttling = false
enable_query_param_based_throttling = false
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://tm.wso2.dev:5675"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
username= "admin_tm"
password= "admin_tm"
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://tm.wso2.dev:9614"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://tm.wso2.dev:9714"]
```